# c++ winsock client cannot connect using textbox for host IP

Tags: c++, textbox, ip-address, winsock, connect

I cannot get it connect to my server when i use the host IP from my textbox.
See my code :

```
                    char *bufhost;
                int bufhostlen;
                bufhostlen = GetWindowTextLength(hwndTextBox_ip) + 1;
                GetWindowText(hwndTextBox_ip, bufhost, bufhostlen);
                sockaddr_in sin;
                sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
                sin.sin_port=htons(5060);
                sin.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(bufhost);
                connect(sock,(LPSOCKADDR)(&sin),sizeof(sin));
```

If i use

```
sin.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

It connects without problem.

I really don't know how to get this work (searched for hours...)
Thanks for helping :-)

SOLUTION :

as PermanentGuest told me, i have to allocate memory to my buffer :

```
                    char *bufhost;
                int bufhostlen;
                bufhostlen = GetWindowTextLength(hwndTextBox_ip) + 1;
                bufhost = (char*) malloc(bufhostlen);
                GetWindowText(hwndTextBox_ip, bufhost, bufhostlen);
                sockaddr_in sin;
                sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
                sin.sin_port=htons(5060);
                sin.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(bufhost);
                connect(sock,(LPSOCKADDR)(&sin),sizeof(sin));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for bufhost. Unfortunateley the documentation of [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't mention this explicitly. However for all win32 APIs, this is the common behaviour